# How to install Arc theme Ubuntu GNOME?

Tags: gnome, software-installation, themes

How can one install the Arc GTK+ Theme on Ubuntu GNOME?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Update**

Since some days there is a Wily repository

```
wget http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:Horst3180/xUbuntu_15.10/Release.key
sudo apt-key add - < Release.key 

sudo sh -c "echo 'deb http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/Horst3180/xUbuntu_15.10/ /' >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/arc-theme.list"
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install arc-theme
```

---

Funny question, but ... okay ...

```
wget http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:Horst3180/xUbuntu_15.04/Release.key
sudo apt-key add - < Release.key 

sudo sh -c "echo 'deb http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/Horst3180/xUbuntu_15.04/ /' >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/arc-theme.list"
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install arc-theme
```

[image]

And no, there is no Wily repository.

The requirements:

- Gnome/GTK 3.14, 3.16 or 3.18
- The `gnome-themes-standard` package
- The murrine engine

For more details read the [README.md](https://github.com/horst3180/Arc-theme/blob/master/README.md).

Comment: So if I try and install it on Wily will it not work?

Comment: The screenshot is from my Wily system with GNOME 3.18

Comment: As I see in the URL it states that it is for 15.04 (and thus not only for LTSs), will they update at some point and provide it also for 15.10?

Comment: I have no idea.

Comment: Why is it a funny question?

Comment: Have they got a 15.10 section yet by the way or still on 15.04?

Comment: Updated for Wily

Comment: Is there a Xenial section yet?

Comment: Please update your answer to be more general as I have decided this will be more useful for other users since 15.10 has gone EOL. I have updated my question. Also on 16.10 you can install it from the universe repository under the package name of `arc-theme`.