# How to install murrine engine?

Tags: gnome, software-installation, themes, 15.10

I understand that [I need](https://askubuntu.com/a/689460/364819) to install the murrine engine, but what exactly is it and how do I install it on Ubuntu GNOME 15.10 with GNOME 3.18?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The package for the murrine engine, the cairo-based gtk+-2.0 theme engine is `gtk2-engines-murrine`. `cairo` is a 2D vector graphics library.

```
sudo apt-get install gtk2-engines-murrine
```

The murrine engine is based on clearlooks and approximately 30% faster.